# which word is grammatically correct?

Tags: tenses

Which one is correct?

After throwing their back in to the back of their car they……. more than a mile.

A.drove
B.Had driven
C.Had been driven

Comment: Any of those *might* be right; there is no way of knowing without more context.

Comment: They only had one back?  Is this a football team?

Comment: (The whole thing is nonsense.)

Comment: @HotLicks Actually, when I first read this I expected the correct answer to be *they pushed it*.

Answer (score 1):

'A' is correct: **they drove**

The other two options are for something that had happened before the 'throwing' action. The word 'after' implies this sequence:

1. They threw their back in the back of the car.
2. They drove.

The verb is used in simple past tense for this sequence.

Comment: They could have been doing the throwing while the car was moving.

Comment: Yes, they **could have been doing** that, but obviously they neither **had driven** nor **had been driven**, so you have mentioned an option that is not in the list.

Comment: They got in their car and started driving.  After throwing their (quarter?)back in to the back of their car they had driven more than a mile.

Comment: They got in their car and the coach started driving. After throwing their (quarter?)back in to the back of their car they had been driven more than a mile.

Comment: Past Perfect tense + 'after' is not possible, unless there is a context clearly indicating an event before which something had been happening. If the context is not provided, we have to base on 'after' only.

Comment: The context is provided.

Comment: The context indicates of 'A' choice.

Comment: So, if I have sentence that is perfectly valid in some context, you can pluck that out of that context, deposit it "bare" in some mindless English quiz, and declare it invalid?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22722/discussion-between-javanoobs-and-hot-licks).